# Replacing foreach loops with LINQ expressions

Tags: linq, lambda

replacing the `foreach` loop

```
IList<EmployeeSearch> empItems = new List<EmployeeSearch>();
EmployeeSearch empItem = new EmployeeSearch();

foreach (var _emp in mediaResults.results)
{
    empItem.Title = _emp.title;
    empItem.Desc = _emp.description;
    empItems.Add(empItem);
}
```

with the following linq expression and getting error:

```
empItems = from _emp in employeeResults.results
           select new EmployeeSearch
           {
               Title = _emp.title,
               Desc = _emp.description                                          
           };
```

Error:

> Error 2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add a call to the [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) extension method at the end of your query:

```
empItems = 
    (from _emp in employeeResults.results
     select new EmployeeSearch
     {
         Title = _emp.title,
         Desc = _emp.description                                          
     })
    .ToList();
```

Or if you can possibly refactor your code to use an `IEnumerable<T>` instead, that could possibly be better:

```
IEnumerable<EmployeeSearch> empItems =
    from _emp in employeeResults.results
    select new EmployeeSearch
    {
        Title = _emp.title,
        Desc = _emp.description                                          
    };
```

This should generally be used if you're just looping through the results and you don't actually need to add / remove elements from the result set or have per-index access to the results. Converting the query results to a list requires allocation of a single, contiguous array in memory, which is a fairly expensive operation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert it to a List:

```
(from _emp in employeeResults.results
                             select new EmployeeSearch
                                 {
                                     Title = _emp.title,
                                     Desc = _emp.description                                          
                                 }).ToList();
```

Or...change your empItems definitions to use a `var` implicit typing:

```
var empItems = from _emp in employeeResults.results
                             select new EmployeeSearch
                                 {
                                     Title = _emp.title,
                                     Desc = _emp.description                                          
                                 };
```

`empItems` will be an `IEnumerable` of `EmployeeSearch` objects.

Comment: i did tried `ToList()` i still get the same error and i am getting red squigle line on select

Comment: you surrounded the whole `from...select...` in parens before calling `ToList()`?